# Adding metadata to a function

Tags: r, attr

I have the following function, on which I want to add a "doc" variable containing metadata:

```
func <- function(x)
{ 
    x
}
attr(func, "doc") = "some documentation"
```

but for sake of clarity I would like to add some metadata IN the function:

```
func <- function(x)
{
    doc = "some documentation in the function"
    x
}
```

however when I try:

```
env = environment(func)
> env$doc
NULL
> get("doc", env)
```

I do not retrieve the informations I need. I am certainly missing a big point!

Comment: If you want access to a variable from a function, you'll have to "return" it. One way to add "meta" information to a function would be to create a package and create as elaborate documentation as you want.

Comment: though you'll probably prefer with R's own documentation system. Having different syntaxes is not a good practice. Try roxygen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure for that:

```
docAdder <- function(fun, doc) {
    newFun <- function(...) {
        vars <- as.list(match.call())
        if(length(vars)<2) {
            return(doc)
        }
        return(fun(...))
    }
    newFun
}
```

This function simply makes the original function return "doc" if there are no supplied arguments.

Then:

```
rev2 <- docAdder(rev, "this function reverses a vector")
rev2(c(1,2,3,4,5))
[1] 5 4 3 2 1
rev2()
[1] "this function reverses a vector
```

However a general way to do this in R is using package and documentation like *Roman* said.